# Strange behavior of Standard Controller`s Save() method on Accounts in Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience

I need help finding a solution of an issue I got. So, I have overriden the Account's Edit and New actions with my custom Visualforce page. This page is build dynamically, based on the used Layout. I collect all the layout fields and pass them to to the Standard Controller's addFields() method. So far so good. When I open a given Account for Edit, everything works like a charm and the Account is edited and saved, but when I want to create a new one, I get an error message saying: No such column 'BillingGeocodeAccuracy ' on entity 'Account'.
The interesting thing is that the Account is actually created inspite the error message, which is shown only in Lightning Experience. I have debugged my code and checked the fields which I pass to the addFields() method - BillingGeocodeAccuracy is NOT one of them, but somehow is included in the SOQL query. I have found a work around which is to use **insert** instead of Standard Sontroller`s **save()** method, but this does not seems right to me. This approach brings other issues like validation ruls not triggering for example. I would much appreciate any help on that. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountExt {

public AccountExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {                             
    this.PageRenderer = new PageRenderer(stdController, 'Account');
}      

public PageRenderer PageRenderer { get; private set; }
```

}

PageRenderer class is where i construct the page. It's pretty big one but i'll try to extract the essential part of it.

The following is part of the Constructor. I get the layout and basically loop trough its components to gather the field names in a collection which I pass to the `addFields` method.

```
            List<String> fields = new List<String>();
            for (LayoutSection section : Layout.Sections) {             
                List<LayoutRow> layoutRows = ExpandLayoutSection(section);

                for(LayoutRow row : layoutRows) {
                    for(LayoutItem layoutItem : row.LayoutItems) {                          
                        if(layoutItem == null || Utils.IsNullOrEmpty(layoutItem.FieldName)) { continue; }

                        fields.add(layoutItem.FieldName);                           

                        for(Integer i = 0; i < layoutItem.CompositeFieldNames.size(); i++) {
                            if(Utils.IsNullOrEmpty(layoutItem.CompositeFieldNames.get(i))) { continue; }

                            fields.add(layoutItem.CompositeFieldNames.get(i));                              
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                

            stdController.addFields(fields);
           //More code here, not relevant to the issue
```

This is my Save() method. If I don't use the `insert stdController.getRecord();` call, I get the mentioned error.

```
public PageReference Save() {       
    PageReference pg = null;
    if(isSalesforce1 && sObjectName == 'Account' && !isEdit){
        insert stdController.getRecord();               
    } else {
        try{
            pg = stdController.save();                                      
        } catch(Exception ex){                  
            Logger.Instance.LogException(ex, false);
        }
    }

    return pg;
}
```

Comment: `BillingGeocodeAccuracy` is part of the Winter 16 release, as well as `ShippingGeocodeAccuracy`. You might want to have a look at [last release known issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=198000000) to see if you can find an answer there.

Comment: Thank you. It seems this is a known issue. I'll stick with my workaround for the moment. Cheers!